# How to get numeric bullets in a Master document in LyX which contains input Lyx documents

Tags: lyx, input, sorting

I want to create a master document in LyX. From there, I want to input (using the meaning of input as in LyX) 4 different LyX documents. Each one of these other LyX documents contains a list of publications, bulleted with numbers. Then I want to get a full list of all the publications that these LyX documents contain, bulleted with numbers, or in other words, sorted using numbers. What I try is, in the master document,  input all of them consecutively. But then I get a list of publications like "1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, ...", and what I want to get is the full list like "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, ...". I do not know how to do this. I tried not using bullets with or without numbers on the input documents, but then I can not get bullets in the master document, any help?

P.S. If there is no LyX solution, I wonder whether this can be done in plain Latex.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the "Customisable lists (enumitem)" module to your master document and each child document. Then change each of your lists from enumerate to enumerate-resume. I haven't tried it, but I think this would do what you want with the numbers.

However, if you want one big list then the spacing won't be right; there will be extra space between the parts of the list in different document. To fix this you will need a LaTeX-based solution. You could implement such a thing in LyX by creating a new layout: a copy of the enumerate layout that issues all the `\item` commands, but doesn't issue a `\begin{enumerate}` or `\end{enumerate}`, leaving you free to issue then yourself where you want them.